# Django rest framework using Template to send an e-mail

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-signals, slugify

I want to send a styled email using HTML tags.
The mail is sent successfully but without style and the HTML tags are presented as a text in the email.

handles.py

```
@receiver(order_created)
def on_order_created(sender, **kwargs):
    order=kwargs['order']
    capture_email= order.customer.user.email
    name= order.customer.user.username
    title= 'Thank you ' + name
    order_items=OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)

    template= render_to_string('index.html',{'order_items':order_items,'name':name})
    # text_content = strip_tags(template)

    email =EmailMessage(
        title,
        template,
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        [capture_email],
        
    )    
    email.fail_silently=False,
    email.send()
```

Comment: Can u add please add some information on how you are managing styles for email template index.html

Answer (score 2):

The [`django.core.mail.EmailMessage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#the-emailmessage-class) class sends an email with the `text/plain` content type, which is why the HTML tags appear. You can have two options:

1. Use the [`django.core.mail.send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#send-mail) function indicating in the `html_message` parameter the result of having rendered the template, something like this:

```py
# quickly example of sending html mail
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import get_template


# I preferred get_template(template).render(context) you can use render_to_string if you want

context = {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Devoe'}
template = get_template('my_custom_template.html').render(context)

send_mail(
    'Custom Subject',
    None, # Pass None because it's a HTML mail
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
    html_message = template
)
```

2. Use the [`django.core.mail.EmailMultiAlternatives`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types) class if you want to implement OOP. So the code will look like this:

```py
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import get_template


# I preferred get_template(template).render(context) you can use render_to_string if you want

context = {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Devoe'}
template = get_template('my_custom_template.html').render(context)

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    'Custom Subject',
    None, # This is the text context, just send None or Send a string message
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
)

msg.attach_alternative(template, "text/html")
msg.send(fail_silently=False)
```

Finally, remember that sending via email will not access static files (for example the application's css) so I recommend using tools such as [Postdrop](https://app.postdrop.io/) that applies css styles to HTML online